# WCF not serializing derived types with ServiceKnownType

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, wsdl

We have a WCF operation which is declared like this in our service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ErrorDetail))]
[ServiceKnownType(GetType(GetUserClassAdministratorResponse))]
[ServiceKnownType(GetType(GetUserClassSupervisorResponse))]
[ServiceKnownType(GetType(GetUserClassRegularResponse))]
public GetUserClassBaseResponse GetUserClass(request As GetUserClassRequest)
```

The logic within the implementation is simple, basically get the corresponding user from the database and instantiate and populate the appropriate `GetUserClassAdministratorResponse` / `GetUserClassSupervisorResponse` / `GetUserClassRegularResponse` depending on the users class.

I note that the WSDL references these service types. That is, I can see the three classes in the WSDL defined correctly, as extensions to GetUserClassBaseResponse.

The issue is that the output for GetUserClass is defined only as the BaseResponse.

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetUserClass">
    <!-- SNIP -->
    <wsdl:output name="GetUserClassBaseResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="ErrorDetailFault">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="ErrorDetailFault" namespace=""/>
    </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

As a result, the object (regardless of its actual type) is being serialized as `GetUserClassBaseResponse`  and therefore the consumers cannot see the extra detail that is included on respective class.

For interest, the `GetUserClassBaseResponse` is defined as:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = “{namespace}”)]
[MessageContract]
public abstract class GetUserClassBaseResponse : BaseResponse
{
    // Properties with [MessageBodyMember] and [DataMember]
}
```

`BaseResponse` simply includes base properties that are common on our system.

Comment: I don't understand why are you using both `DataContract` and `MessagemContract`. MSDN documentation says: *If a type has both a message contract and a data contract, only its message contract is considered when the type is used in an operation.*, as you can see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx

Comment: @RicardoPontual Thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of that.